# Parse json string to json array issue

Tags: java, android, json, string

I have data coming from web-service in android like this:

```
"[{\"ID\":9617,\"Text\":\"1 1\/4\\\" PVC\/GI CLAMPS\"},{\"ID\":41608,\"Text\":\"100123-Manterial name\"}]"
```

Now the issue is I want to parse this json data to json array but it gives me error exception due to double quote(") within string , I try to remove back slashes manually. I use code like this to convert it to json array.

```
String line="[{\"ID\":9617,\"Text\":\"1 1\/4\\\" PVC\/GI CLAMPS\"},{\"ID\":41608,\"Text\":\"100123-Manterial name\"}]";
String  jsonFormattedString = line.replace("\\\\", "");
jsonFormattedString= jsonFormattedString.substring(1, jsonFormattedString.length()-1) ;
Log.d("Json String--->",jsonFormattedString);

JSONArray j = new JSONArray(jsonFormattedString);//here I get exception cannot covert to json array 

JSONObject jsonmain = j.getJSONObject(0);

int lengthJsonArr = j.length();

for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {

    jsonmain = j.getJSONObject(i);
    Log.d("Jsonnnnn----",jsonmain.getString("Text"));
    Itm=new CItem(jsonmain.getString("ID"),jsonmain.getString("Text"));
    lstItm.add(Itm);
}
```

Comment: Omg, I know this problem. You're creating a `JSONObject` which is already a `JSONObject`. So ask your php developer to change this format and try to  create  a `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this?

```
String  jsonFormattedString = line.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: You're using replace, not replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
public String convertStandardJSONString(String data_json){
    data_json = data_json.replace("\\", "");
    data_json = data_json.replace("\"{", "{");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\",", "},");
    data_json = data_json.replace("}\"", "}");
    return data_json;
}
```

@REF: Cristy YG

Comment: I think your JSON is invalid.

Comment: No it is only thing is data contain double quotes within it.

Comment: `Strings should be wrapped in double quotes`, why you want to escape those quotes?

Comment: @mubu9082 : use this tool to validate your JSON http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static String convertStandardJSONString(String data_json) {
      data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");
      data_json = data_json.replace("\"{", "{");
      data_json = data_json.replace("}\",", "},");
      data_json = data_json.replace("}\"", "}");
      return data_json;
  }
```

1. Make sure your JSON is valid first. Copy and paste them here (jsonlint.com) and
   check it is valid or not.
2. If you json is valid. Try above method (`convertStandardJSONString`).
3. You need to know the response JSON structure. You can't parse JSONObject to JSONArray or JSONArray to JSONObject.